# Es posible enviar solicitudes paralelas desde una sola conexión WebSocket

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, asyncio

Estoy usando [WebSockets 7](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) y todo va bien, varios usuarios pueden conectarse al websocket, enviar solicitudes y recibir respuestas del servidor, pero hay un problema.

Si un usuario envía a imagen, pdf, canción, video, etc. El servidor debe resolver eso, guardar en db, convertir, etc. y enviar la respuesta, el usuario podría enviar más datos a websocket pero esos datos se pondrán en cola hasta que se reciba el mensaje anterior. respuesta, eso no es bueno, cuando los usuarios están desesperados por enviar datos en el menor tiempo posible.

¿Existe la posibilidad de que un usuario conectado envíe solicitudes paralelas?

Este es el ejemplo que estoy usando

```
import asyncio
import websockets

# Process the data
async def read(msg, websocket):
    # In this case, the message will get back to the user
    if msg == 'long':
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
    elif msg == 'short':
        pass

    print("Did a {0} task".format(msg))
    await websocket.send(msg)

async def counter(websocket, path):
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            await read(message, websocket)
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        websockets.serve(counter, '0.0.0.0', 4444, max_size=10**8))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

También he intentado usar loop:

```
import asyncio
import websockets

# Process the data
async def read(msg, websocket):
    # In this case, the message will get back to the user
    if msg == 'long':
        import time
        time.sleep(5)
    elif msg == 'short':
        pass

    print("Did a {0} task".format(msg))
    await websocket.send(msg)

async def counter(websocket, path):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            loop.create_task(read(message, websocket))
    except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
        pass

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(
        websockets.serve(counter, '0.0.0.0', 4444, max_size=10**8))
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
```

Cuando envío "long", y "short" de forma simultanea, "long" hace esperar a "short" hasta que se complete y responda. :(

Comment: ¿Cómo haces los envíos "de forma simultánea"?

Comment: Envio, "long" y "short" uno justo despues del otro, entonces son 2 solicitudes.

Comment: Sí, pero no son simultáneas, Va una tras otra, y además entiendo que ambas por el mismo websocket. El websocket es un solo "canal" en cada dirección, similar a TCP. Los mensajes están ordenados en el orden en que se emitieron. Por otro lado no veo claro por qué usar un websocket para enviar "mucha información" del cliente al servidor ¿no sería mejor usar un HTTP PUT o POST? Esos sí pueden paralelizarse (porque el navegador típicamente abre varias conexiones TCP simultáneas con el mismo servidor, para disminuir las latencias)